# R why does difference between POSIXlt has a decimal part?

Tags: r, date, posixlt

Why does difference between POSIXlt has a decimal part whereas difference between Date hasn't?

Example:

```
as.POSIXlt("2015-12-10",format = "%Y-%m-%d")-as.POSIXlt("2015-10-07",format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

returns `64.04167`

```
as.Date("2015-12-10",format = "%Y-%m-%d")-as.Date("2015-10-07",format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

returns `64` (correct value)

Why the different behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These decimals amount to exactly one hour, which occurred during the switch from DST.

```
0.04167 * 24
#[1] 1.00008
#some rounding error
```

Specify a time zone without DST and you get this:

```
as.POSIXlt("2015-12-10",format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "GMT")-
  as.POSIXlt("2015-10-07",format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "GMT")
#Time difference of 64 days
```

Comment: To clarify to other readers: DST = Daylight Saving Time. If you pick two dates both with dst (march-october) or without dst (november-february) there will be no decimal part.